# How to add extra column in Item ordered tab in Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order

How to add an extra column in Item ordered tab in Magento 2?

PFA

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a new column at then you have to work on below files:

[**sales_order_view.xml**](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml)

Create `sales_order_view.xml` at your module `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/view/adminhtml/layout`

**and add a new column using below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customcol" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom column</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>  
            <block class="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Block\Adminhtm\Items\Column\Custom" name="column_customcol" 
                   template="{Vendor}_{ModuleName}::items/column/custom.phtml" group="column"/>         
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customcol" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-customcol</item>
                </argument>  
            </arguments>             
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Here `customcol` is a unique identifier for the new column**.

BLock class `Column.php` for showing content.Location `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Block/Adminhtml/Items/Column/Custom.php`

**and Code:**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column;


class Custom  extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn
{

}
```

Phtml `custom.phtml` file for this block `app/code/{Vendor}/Magento/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/custom.phtml`

**and Code is:**

```
<?php
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
?>
<?php
/* @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name */
?>
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()) : ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note**

Replace `{Vendor}` with Your module vendor name and 
{ModuleName} replace Module Name.

Comment: thank you sir. it's working now

Comment: @Devidas please mark the answer as solved if the answer solves your question.

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo, thank but you cannot ask the user accept this his/her answer

Comment: @AmitBera I have tried this solution for 2.3.5 version and it is not working anymore. Can u please guide here. I have defined Block Custom in magentoroot/app/code/MyModule/Customadmin/etc/adminhtml/di.xml. But still it not working .